# MissingMemberException: Method Not Found when invoking a method

Tags: c#, invoke

I am learning how to call a method dynamically based on a method name passed as a string. The best way I could understand is invoking a method. I am trying to invoke a method by passing its class name and method name. But it always gives me the exception

> Method not found.

I have tried clean up and rebuild all. Still it's not working.

```cs
namespace TestInvoking
{
    class Invoke
    {
        public string InvokeMember(string method, string para)
        {
            try
            {
                string Result = (string)typeof(Invoke).InvokeMember(method, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase
                                        | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                                        null, null, new Object[] { para });
                return Result;
            }
            catch (MissingMemberException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to access the testMethod field: {0}", e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void testMethod(string tri)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("methodInvoked - {0}", tri);
        }
    }
```

```cs
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Invoke methodInvoke = new Invoke();
            text.Text = methodInvoke.InvokeMember("testMethod", "Method_Invoked");
        }
```

Comment: Hint: `testMethod` isn't a `static` method, so you need an instance to call it on. You're currently passing `null` for this. Also, `testMethod` is `void`, not `string`.

Comment: Contrarily, you're passing the `BindingFlags.Static` flag, indicating that you expect it to be static. That's why you get `MissingMemberException` instead of, say, `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Im not much into reflection, but my guess is that you did not instantiate a class nor pass the `target` parameter.

Comment: In this case the instance you would pass is `this`.

Comment: @madreflection That is my suggestion in the answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

1. You are passing `BindingFlags.Static` but the method is not static.
2. You are passing `null` to the target. As long as the `InvokeMember` is not
   static, hence you already have an instance, you could just pass the
   parameter.

After doing both changes the code would be as follows.

```
class Invoke
{
    public string InvokeMember(string method, string para)
    {
        try
        {
            string Result = (string)typeof(Invoke).InvokeMember(method, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, this, new Object[] { para });
            return Result;
        }
        catch (MissingMemberException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to access the testMethod field: {0}", e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void testMethod(string tri)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("methodInvoked - {0}", tri);
    }


}
```

Comment: I just noticed this: `BindingFlags.CreateInstance` doesn't apply here. Your second point need *only* be about passing `this` instead of `null`.

Comment: @madreflection Why not? because of lack of constructor?

Comment: The creation already happened in `Button_Click`, and it exists as `this` in `Invoke.InvokeMember`. All `Type.InvokeMember` has to do, as indicated by the `BindingFlags.InvokeMethod` flag, is find the `MethodInfo` for the method, match the provided arguments to the right signature (using the default binder because the `binder` parameter is `null`), and then call `MethodInfo.Invoke`.

Comment: I am not expert in this but when I include `BinderFlags.CreateInstance` it doesn't work but when I include `BinderFlags.Instance` it worked as desired. Afterwards I checked theory part of both and found `CreateInstance` is used if `Constructor` needs to be called and `Instance` is used when member of that particular  instance needs to be included. Correct me if my understanding is wrong. In my case I only needed to search member of instance therefore `BinderFlags.Instance` shall be used.

Comment: @braveYug: You are correct. **Some clarification:** `Instance` and `CreateInstasnce` both have "instance" in the name but they're unrelated. `BindingFlags` has several sets of flags, including: `Static` vs. `Instance` (choose one); `Public` vs. `NonPublic` (choose either *or* both); when passed to the `InvokeMember` method, the *invocation action*: `CreateInstance`, `InvokeMethod`, `GetProperty`, `SetProperty`, `GetField`, `SetField`, etc. which are mutually exclusive.

Comment: (Actually, you might be able to specify both `Static` and `Instance` (I've never needed to do that) but then you'd have to know more about what you're doing with what you find in order to invoke it correctly.)